# Accessing Documentum Server version 6.5 through C# app using DFC PIA 5.3

Tags: .net, pia, documentum6.5

Can we Login to a Documentum Docbase version 6.5 from a C# application using an older PIA (Primary Interop Assembly version 5.3). I know PIA has been deprecated since version 6.5 but I have DFC 5.3 and PIA 5.3. Is this possible? Are these two versions compatible with each other?

Answer (score 1):

The older PIA is compatable but will not have any functions/features added after 5.3. I've worked on a project where we wrapped it in a separate .NET library and then the application called the .NET code which in turned called the PIA. It was tested against a 6.5 content server and repository.